# External JS Method within DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I have a message box that I want to populate with text based upon the data returned from an external JavaScript file.

However, the method is failing to execute.

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-box" id="x">
        <div class="sticky-inner" id="sticky_inner"><script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_file_"></script><script>getText();</script></div>
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="I agree" onclick="save()"/>
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value ="I disagree" onclick="hide()"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function getText()
    {       
        return "hi";
    }
```

It's probably something simple, Bit I've searched around and I couldn't find a resolution :/

Comment: Just returning a value from a function does not place that value into an HTML element in any way. One could either use `document.write` (not recommended), or access the element via its id and write the desired element content via `.innerHTML=…`

Comment: @CBroe I needed the your suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getText` method just returns a string. It doesn't modify the HTML and you don't do anything with the return value.

1. Turn the string into a text node (e.g. with [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode)).
2. Find an element to put it in (e.g. with [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)).
3. Add the text node to the element (e.g. with [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
That makes perfect sense and it is all working with the getElement function :D

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getText() {
        alert('hi');
        return "hi";
    }
</script><div class="sticky-box" id="x">
    <div class="sticky-inner" id="sticky_inner">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_file_"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            getText();
        </script>
    </div>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="I agree" onclick="save()" />
    <input id="btn2" type="button" value="I disagree" onclick="hide()" />
</div>
```